# Error re-directing a page to the subsequent page after successful login

Tags: php, html, pdo

I have this contact form. I want that after filling the form and clicking the submit button, my script checks if the user is logged in. If the user is not logged in, he is redirected to the login page to login and after that, he sees a 'thanks for filling the form'. I don't know how to do this, my script redirects the user back to an empty contact form after login and then the user will once again, have to fill the fields. How do i solve this?

contact.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$location= urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
if (isset($_SESSION['id']) == false){
    echo "You have to be <a href='login.php?location=$location'>logged in</a>";
}else{
//Insert into database 
//thanks for filling the form
}
?>
//Contact form fields
```

login.php

```
<?php
if (login details is true) {
             $redirect = NULL;
             $redirect = $_GET['location'];
             header("Location:". $redirect);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php  //Start the Session
session_start();
 require('connect.php');
//If the form is submitted or not. and If the form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])){
//Assigning posted values to variables.
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//Checking the values are existing in the database or not
$query = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
//If the posted values are equal to the database values, then session will be created for the user.
if ($count == 1){
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{
//If the login credentials doesn't match, he will be rediret with an error message.
header("Location:yourpage.php?msg=Invalid Login Credentials");
exit;
}
}
//if the user is logged in Greets the user with message
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
echo "Hai " . $username . "
";
echo "This is the Members Area
";
echo "<a href='logout.php'>Logout</a>";

}else{
header("Location:register.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you explain this? plus `session_register()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php is deprecated as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0. Plus, why the use of a deprecated MySQL API?

Comment: @Fred-ii- My Bad Fred .. actually i used this code before a year might be.. thanks for marking will update it.

Comment: If the OP is using 5.4 then this `session_register()` won't work, sorry to say.

Answer (score 0):

Once logged in convert the user credentials to sessions like his contact id,contact name to use this in the whole project for this kind of checks.....
here in contact form you will be gettin the session details if the user is logged in to your website for example you are converting his contact id into session like this if he is logged in as `$_SESSION['CONTACT_ID'];`
Then you can have check with this session id incontact page at the top as

```
 <?
    $redirect = "login.php";
    if($_SESSION['CONTACT_ID']=='')
    {
     header("Location:". $redirect);
    }
?>
```

if the user is not logged in then he will not be able to use contact page and will be redirected to login page

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to save what your user put inside each field, you can do that passing your $_POST to $_SESSION;

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['example'] = $_POST['dataFromForm'];
...
```

When the user logged, you can retrieve these data $_SESSION inside your fields (html form):

```
<input type="text" name="something" value="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['example'])):$_SESSION['example']?''; "/>
```